# Vehicle registration task

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file = open("Speeders.txt", "w")
import random, string, time
Speeders = [] #Array

while True:
    try:
        Distance = float(input("Enter a known distance.(Metres ONLY)"))
        break
    except ValueError: #Allows ONLY numbers to be inputted, anything else is rejected
        print ("Invalid input (Numbers ONLY)")

while True:
    try:
        TimeTaken = float(input("Enter the time taken to pass the distance"))
        break
    except ValueError:#Allows ONLY numbers to be inputted, anything else is rejected
        print ("Invalid input (Numbers ONLY)")

while True:
    try:
        Limit = int(input("Enter the speed limit in metres per second"))
        break
    except ValueError:#Allows ONLY numbers to be inputted, anything else is rejected
        print ("Invalid input (Numbers ONLY)")

Speed = (Distance) / (TimeTaken)
print (("The speed of the vehicle was " + str(Speed) + " metres per second"))
while True:
    try:
        if (Speed) > (Limit):
            def NumPlate(self):
                plateFormat = ['L', 'L', 'N', 'N', 'L', 'L', 'L']
                NumPlate = []

                for i in plateFormat:
                    if i == 'L':
                        NumPlate.append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters[26:]))

                    elif i == 'N':
                        NumPlate.append(str(random.randint(0, 9)))
                        NumPlate.insert(4, " ")
                        NumPlate = str(input("Enter the vehicle's number plate."))
                        Speeders.append (NumPlate)
                        return  "".join(NumPlate)
                    break




        while True:
            reply = input('Enter Y to add another number plate N to print list: ')

            if reply == "Y":
                while True:
                    try:
                        Distance = float(input("Enter a known distance.(Metres ONLY)"))
                        break
                    except ValueError: #Allows ONLY numbers to be inputted, anything else is rejected
                        print ("Invalid input (Numbers ONLY)")

                while True:
                    try:
                        TimeTaken = float(input("Enter the time taken to pass the distance"))
                        break
                    except ValueError:#Allows ONLY numbers to be inputted, anything else is rejected
                        print ("Invalid input (Numbers ONLY)")

                while True:
                    try:
                        Limit = int(input("Enter the speed limit in metres per second"))
                        break
                    except ValueError:#Allows ONLY numbers to be inputted, anything else is rejected
                        print ("Invalid input (Numbers ONLY)")

                Speed = (Distance) / (TimeTaken)
                print (("The speed of the vehicle was " + str(Speed) + " metres per second"))

                if (Speed) > (Limit):
                        NumPlate = str(input("Enter the vehicle's number plate."))
                        Speeders.append (NumPlate)

                        while True:
                            reply = input('Enter Y to add another number plate N to print list: ')

                file.write("Here is a list of the Speeders' number plates on the roads\n")
                file.write("List" + str(Speeders))

            if reply == "N":
                for i in Speeders:
                    print("This is the list of current number plates that are speeding: " + str(Speeders))
```

Comment: Could you add more context to your question? As it stands, we have no description of what this code does, so it's harder for us to give good reviews.

Comment: These are the questions given, this code is my answer to part a) and b) any help/corrections would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This is a copy of *this now deleted* [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31092659/581205). This is fine, as it seems to belong here, but why don't you copy the text, too?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's nothing more than a code dump. No context, no question, no nothing.

Comment: Helping you fix broken code is for Stack Overflow. Reviewing working code and suggesting possible improvements is for Code Review. When you said "improve or fix" it on StackOverflow, everyone jumped to push the question here, but since this code doesn't work, that was a bad recommendation. The very big block all sits inside a `try:` block, with no `except:` at the end, that means it won't even try to run - you've either missed copying some into your question, or ... worse.

Answer (score 3):

First off, variables and functions should be in `snake_case`, not `PascalCase`. Only classes should be in `PascalCase`. If you have a variable with an unchangining value, (constant), it should be in `UPPERCASE_SNAKE_CASE`.

Secondly, I'm noticing that you're putting variables in parentheses in a lot of your expressions. For example, `Speed = (Distance) / (TimeTaken)` can become `speed = distance / time_taken`, or `if (Speed) > (Limit)` can become `if speed > speed_limit`.

You should be using [context managers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to manage files. When you just use `open()`, and then close it using `.close()`, certain memory issues can occur. The proper way to open a file can be seen in the below example:

```
with open("path/to/myfile", "w") as file_name:
    # Do stuff with file_name
```

Using this method, there's no need to call `.close()` on the file, and the file is closed explicitly, so you don't need to worry about memory issues.

I notice that you repeat the `Speed = (Distance) / (TimeTaken)` a lot. Preferably, when you have repetition like this in your code, you can shorten it into a function. In this case, I'd create the following function:

```
def calculate_speed(distance, time_taken):
    return distance / time_taken
```

Finally, add some comments to this code. You don't need comments everywhere, but you should add some in places where your code may be slightly harder to understand just by reading it.

---

*For any style guide tips, see Python's official style guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).*

Comment: `add some comments to this code` this is a matter of personal preference. There are people stating the exact opposite, code should be self describing. I'm on neither side, but comments aren't necessary if the code is clear enough. Best case this code gets cleared up far enough comments aren't even necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just going to focus on the function `NumPlate`, because otherwise I'd be writing a novel in this answer.

First: It's defined in a weird place. Is there any particular reason why you only want it to exist if `Speed > Limit`?

Second: Why is the only argument `self` when it's not an instance method?

Third: I cannot for the life of me tell what this function is supposed to do. Right now, you have `NumPlate = str(input("Enter the vehicle's number plate."))`, which makes me suspect that the user is supposed to enter in a  plate number, but then you have all of that randomization stuff as well.

Fourth: As is, that `for` loop is effectively useless. The first letter of  `plateFormat` is defined as `'L'`, so the loop hits the first `if` block, skips the `elif` block, hits that `break` statement, and exits the function (returning `None` because it never hit a return statement).